# Edge-synchronization failed, invalid credentials

Tags: exchange-2007

We have a simple Exchange 2007 setup with Mailbox, Hub Transport, CAS and Edge Transfer. The Edge Transport server is located outside AD in a DMZ.

My problem starts 24 hours after successfully configuring the edge-subscription as per Microsoft's guidelines on technet... I get InvalidCredentials and the synchronization fails.

It looks to me like renewal of the bootstrap-synchronization account fails.

How can this happen? Why does it happen? I can't find anything wrong with the setup or the subscription. It works excellent for 24 hours, but fails. When I renew, it works for 24 hours again.

Mostly Windows Server 2008 x64, some Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 in the setup.

Could use some input on this error. Anyone experienced this before?

Comment: Looks like the Microsoft Exchange Credential Service had stopped. Started it, but won't know more until tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the service "Microsoft Edge Credential Service" on the Edge-Transfer server had stopped, and this caused the "InvalidCredentials" to pop up in the eventlog on the Hub Transport server. Therefore I'll just keep monitoring this service for a few weeks, and hope it doesn't stop again.

I fixed this by starting the aforementioned service, and made sure it was still active today. I guess this problem would have gone away after a reboot, like so many other issues :-P